# IF ROWS IS ALL EQUAL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use CASE WHEN Command, if my column `IsApproved` is all equal to 1 then the display is `'COMPLETE'` then if there's still 0 then it is pending, depending on the `ResignTxn` number. How can I do that?

For example, if there's still 0 in txn number 45, then the output must be 
pending, then if all the value is 1  then it must be complete.

[image]

Comment: Please include some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 3):

Try below query:

```
select ResignTxn,
       -- it counts 0 in particular ResignTxn
       case when sum(case when isApproved = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'pending' else 'complete' end
from MyTable
group by ResignTxn
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(IsApproved) =0 THEN 'Pending' ELSE 'Complete' END AS Status
FROM [Table]
Group by ResignTxn
```

Answer (score 1):

Check min value

```
select  ResignTxn , case min(IsApproved) when 1 then `COMPLETE'  else 'pending' end
from mytable
group by ResignTxn
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would leave the logic out of the DB, just get the relevant data and evaluate it in your application, but you can do it like this if you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS countResult
WHERE IsApproved=0,
CASE
    WHEN countResult > 0 THEN "PENDING"
    ELSE "COMPLETE"
END AS ResultText
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use:

```
select case when IsApproved = 1 then 'Complete' else 'Pending' end as Status
from YOURTABLE
```

Comment: Thats not providing the requested aggregation.